# OpenBSD 6.8 TrackPoint and TouchPad issue

Tags: x11, openbsd, touchpad, thinkpad

I have lenovo L390 Thinkpad laptop. Is it possible to configure trackpoint and touchpad? I tried this lines, but nothing happened, only my usb mouse working well

```
xinput set-prop "/dev/wsmouse" "WS Pointer Wheel Emulation" 1
xinput set-prop "/dev/wsmouse" "WS Pointer Wheel Emulation Axes" 6 7 4 5
xinput set-prop "/dev/wsmouse" "WS Pointer Wheel Emulation Button" 2
xinput set-prop "/dev/wsmouse" "WS Pointer Wheel Emulation Timeout" 50
xinput set-prop "/dev/wsmouse" "WS Pointer Wheel Emulation Inertia" 3
```

Сan anyone come across such a problem and know the solution?
regards, max

UPD1: my touchpad worked after I closed and opened my laptop. But I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Add this line, logout and see what happens ;)

**xinput set-prop "/dev/wsmouse" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 0.3**

Comment: I write this line in terminal. press mod+shift+q (dwm manager)    and nothing happened. Еhe cursor does not move.